# Distinct Records in Entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to Distinct List of Data

My Code:

```
PendingGRemsResult _Return = new PendingGRemsResult();

_Return.PendingGRemsResultRecord = Context.Where(a => a.Status == 0)
   .Select(s => new PendingGRemsResultRecord
     { GUID = s.GRemGUID.GUID,
       Count = App.GroupedRemittance
         .GetByFilter((gr => gr.GRemGUID.GUID == s.GRemGUID.GUID))
         .Count(),
       CreatorType = s.GRemGUID.CreatorType.Value})
  .Distinct()
  .ToList();

return _Return;
```

this code not working data sill duplicated

Comment: Do you have `Equals` and `GetHashCode` overridden on PendingGRemsResultRecord class?

Comment: no i donnot @SergeyBerezovskiy

Comment: By which property you want to make a distinction?

Comment: @user3152935 I updated answer to explain how it works and what was wrong with your approach, it should be interesting to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
_Return.PendingGRemsResultRecord = 
     Context.Where(a => a.Status == 0)
            .Select(a => new {
               a.GRemGUID.GUID, 
               CreatorType = a.s.GRemGUID.CreatorType.Value })
            .Distinct()
            .Select(x => new PendingGRemsResultRecord {
                  GUID = x.GUID,
                  Count = App.GroupedRemittance
                             .GetByFilter(gr => gr.GRemGUID.GUID == x.GUID)
                             .Count(),
                  CreatorType = x.CreatorType
              }).ToList();
```

UPDATE: How it works - thus you don't have `Equals` and `GetHashCode` specified on you `PendingGRemsResultRecord` class, then instances of this class will be compared by reference. And that will treat all instances to be different, even if they have same values of properties. You have several possibilities to teach `Distinct()` method to look on values instead of comparing references (override `Equals` and `GetHasCode`, create and pass custom comparer) but you also can use power of anonymous objects, which have default `Equals` and `GetHashCode` implementations that use values of properties to check if two anonymous objects are equal.

That's exactly what I use here - projecting source sequence objects into anonymous objects with `GUID` and `CreatorType` properties. Then with power of default comparison of anonymous objects you can use `Distinct()` to get only objects with different guid and creator type. Next is simple projecting of distinct results to your `PendingGRemsResultRecord`.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 3 solutions to this challenge:

1. Use `DistinctBy()` method with lambda expression, example:

   `var query = someData.DistinctBy(x => x.PropertyYouWantToDistinquishBy)`;
2. Build an equalityComparer that will implement the interface`IEqulityComparer<PendingGRemsResultRecord>` and then use an instance of this class for the overload od `Distinct()` method.
3. Implement the `IEquatable` interface in your `PendingGRemsResultRecord` class (with `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods).